# Prove that if $T(n) = T(n - 1) + \Theta(n)$, then $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283866/proof-by-the-substitution-method-that-if-tn-tn-1-thetan-then-tn) question, the top answer shows how to prove that $T(n) = O(n^2)$, but not that $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$.  I am struggling with this last half of the proof.

This is what I get when I try to prove it:

$$
\begin{align}
T(n)&= T(n-1)+cn\\
    &\geq k(n-1)^2+cn\\
    &=kn^2 - 2kn + k + cn
\end{align}
$$

In order for the proof to work, we need $kn^2 - 2kn + k + cn \geq kn^2$.  I try to prove this below:

$$
\begin{align}
kn^2 - 2kn + k + cn &\geq kn^2 \\
-2kn + k + cn &\geq 0 \\
k(-2n + 1) &\geq -cn \\
k(2n - 1) &\leq cn \\
k &\leq c*  \frac{n}{2n-1} \\
\end{align}
$$

I know that the RHS of this equation will always be greater than $\frac{c}{2}$.  Thus, if we choose any $k \leq \frac{c}{2}$, that last statement will always be true, and the chain of logic proves $T(n) \geq kn^2$ (thus completing our proof).

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea seems correct, though you made a slight mistake in the beginning, so I would recommend writing out exactly what properties you are using to prove both of these lines:
$$T(n) = T(n-1) + cn$$
$$     \geq k(n-1)^2 + cn    .$$

One is incorrect and the other is a part of your strategy.

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I think I see what I did wrong - the first statement should have had an $\geq$, not an $=$ (because $T(n) = T(n - 1) + \Theta(n) \geq  T(n - 1) + cn$).  Aside from that - does the proof look ok?

Comment: It looks fine. I would just add in an explanation of your methodology. For instance, how would you explain the second line: 
$$T(n-1) + cn \geq k(n-1)^2 + cn?$$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.  I would probably say something like "By our inductive hypothesis, ..."

Answer (score 1):

$T(n) = T(n - 1) + \Theta(n)$ implies $T(n) \ge T(n - 1) + cn$ for some $c$. Now sum both sides:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N T(n) \ge \sum_{n=2}^N (T(n-1) + cn) =  \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} T(n) + \sum_{n=2}^N cn
$$
and so
$$
T(N) \ge \sum_{n=2}^N cn = c \sum_{n=2}^N n = c  \dfrac{N^2 + N - 2}{2} >  \dfrac{c}{2}N^2
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help @lhf.  Unfortunately I need to use a substitution proof for this problem.  Was my substitution proof incorrect?